# How does one create a Google doc directly in a folder?

Tags: google-drive

I clicked on a Google doc folder and created a new Google doc. However, the Google doc is not automatically placed in the folder.

How do I create a document and have it automatically belong to a folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the collection (folder) and, from the popup menu, select Create -> Document.

Alternatively, you can click the downward pointing arrow that appears when you hover over the folder to get the same contextual popup menu.